# nuxt js style scoped i can't figure out how to change the style of another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Please help me figure out how  works. The  documentation states that it changes the style only in the zone of one component, but what if I need to change the style of another component depending on the component on the page. For example, I have a  component (Footer.vue), it is connected in the default component (layouts / default.vue) Nuxt. and there are many pages (pages / ...) that will be included in (layouts / default.vue) using the  tag.
i use

```
<style scoped>

#content-wrapper[data-v-314f53c6] >>> footer[data-v-0d2d6594] {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

and

```
<style scoped>
    
    footer[data-v-0d2d6594] {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    </style>
```

It doesn't work like that.

Screenshots of my project

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please tell me how it works, and how best to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried it without `scoped`?

```
<style>

#content-wrapper footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried, but in this case, the style will be declared globally, and will act on all pages, and I need to act only on certain